# How to call ObjectContext.Refresh() when using ADO.NET Unit Testable Repository Generator

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, t4, objectcontext

I'm using “**ADO.NET Unit Testable Repository Generator**" ([described here](http://blog.johanneshoppe.de/2010/10/walkthrough-ado-net-unit-testable-repository-generator/)) to generate the entity classes. This T4 template automatically generates the following classes, apart from the classes for the database objects:

1. **<*MyEntities*>.cs** -     The functional concrete object context
2. **<*MyEntities*>BaseRepositoryTest.cs**
3. **<*MyEntities*>Mock.cs** -  The concrete mock context object that implements the context's interface.
4. **<*MyEntities*>Mock.ObjectSet.cs**
5. **<*MyModelRepository*>.Context.cs**
6. **<*MyEntities*>PartialRespository.cs**
7. **I<*MyEntities*>.cs** -    The interface for the specialised object context.

I am not completely sure what some of these classes are for.

I am using a manager class that performs all database access/update operations.

```
// Contains all Methods that access the database 
public class DataManager
{
    private IMyEntities _context;

    public DataManager()
        : this(new MyEntities())
    {
    }

    public bool AddOrder(Order order)
    {
      _context.Orders.AddObject(order);
      _context.SaveChanges();
    }
  ...
  }
```

i want to check for concurrency exceptions when I call `_context.SaveChanges()`. Ideally, I would like to call `_context.Refresh()` in case of a concurrency issue. However, the autogenerated ObjectContext class `IMyEntities` does have a method like `ObjectContext.Refresh()`

What am I doing wrong? How can I call Refresh()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this can't be done since `IMyEntities` does not inherit `ObjectContext`.
But `MyEntities` does.

When I change

> private IMyEntities _context;

to

> private MyEntities _context;

I can call `ObjectContext.Refresh()` using `_context.Refresh()`.